# Write a SQL query for finding Highest Partnership for each match in IPL database using the table ball_by_ball

Tags: sql

Table of ball_by_ball:

| ball_by_ball |
| --- |
| match_id |
| innings_no |
| over_id |
| ball_id |
| runs_scored |
| extra_runs |
| out_type |
| striker |
| non_striker |
| bowler |

Find the ids of players who got the highest no of partnership runs for each match. There can be multiple rows for a single match. Output <match_id, player1_id, player2_id, runs1, runs2, pship_runs>(player1’s contribution i.e. runs1 >= player2’s contribution i.e. runs2 ), in descending order of pship_runs (incase of ties compare match_id in ascending order). If runs1=runs2  then player1_id > player2_id.

Note: extra_runs shouldn’t be counted

As I am new to sql, I have no idea how to proceed. Please help me out

Any ideas how to proceed are appreciated

Comment: Please give sample input output with you table schema. It will be helpful to check your problem. :-)

Comment: We have to write a sql query. I don't have a sample input output but I do have a table schema picture

Comment: What is a "partnership run"?  The question is not clear.

Comment: Its same as partnership in cricket

Comment: @Abra . . . Not at all.  Questions on StackOverfow are not about Cricket.  They are about programming.  The question should contain enough domain information to be understandable.

Comment: Partnership: Cricket has 2 batsmen who are "in" at any one time and each combination of these 2 batsmen is called a partnership - so all runs scored by either of them will be added to their partnership score. As soon as one of them is "out", and another batsman is "in", then a new partnership will start with a zero partnership score. Partnerships don't actually have any affect on the game; much like baseball, it is all about statistics because the game itself is so boring they have to make up irrelevant statistics so there is something to talk about

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will probably get you close to what you want:

```
SELECT
t1.striker||'-'||t1.non_striker as "Partnership"
,sum(t1.runs_scored + t2.runs_scored) as "Partnership_Runs"
from cricket_scores t1
inner join cricket_scores t2 on t1.striker = t2.non_striker and t1.non_striker = t2.striker
where t1.striker < t2.striker -- Ensures the partnership is only counted once
group by t1.striker||'-'||t1.non_striker;
```